# Quick replies or suggestion with watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson, watson-dialog

We are working on FB messenger app which use IBM watson conversation for AI bot. But, we need quick replies like provided by [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#add-quick-replies-to-my-bot).

Is there any way to get quick replies or suggestion from watson conversation while getting message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conversation API receives a text message and understands its intention giving the user an answer. It does not offer any kind of quick-replay or interface enhancements.

What you could do is develop this function in your integration software. Using wit.ai example:

```
User: “I want to order”
```

The integration software sends this message to Watson. It finds out that is the intention **#order** and send it back to the integration software. Instead of just send the answer to the user, knowing the **#order** intention, the integration software builds a quick reply:

```
Bot: “For here? yes or no?”
```

And you go on. You can build any kind of quick reply using images or buttons, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Danilo. We don't offer this service out of the box at this point. Wit obviously has a greater allegiance with Facebook than we do, so that is much more their focus. We may get there over time as it is a very popular channel. I would do something similar to Danilo mentioned.

In my output object coming from watson, I would put some indicator to include buttons.
"outputs": {
"text": "Do you want for here or to go?",
"quickreply": {"for here", "to go" }
}

and then your client side code needs to know to put whatever is in the click reply section into buttons for messenger specifically. If that's invalid Json, sorry, but I hope it gets the point across. You will need to do this manually for now though.